# Custom Grid Lines for ProbabilityScalePlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, grid-lines

I'm plotting up some data using a `ProbabilityScalePlot` in Mathematica 8. It currently looks like so:

[image: ProbabilityScalePlot, Automatic Gridlines]

Code:

```
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", AspectRatio -> 0.9, Frame -> True, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, Axes -> False, 
    LabelStyle -> font, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize -> Large, Thick, Purple], 
    FrameLabel -> {"Value", "Cum. Prob."}, ImageSize -> 250]
```

**I'd like to change the y grid lines to only show up on the ticks `{1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, 99}` but when I change `GridLines -> Automatic` to `GridLines -> {Automatic,Ticks}` I get an  error.**

The error is "A GridLines specification should be None, Automatic, or a list of grid line specifications."

What's odd is that doing the same thing on a different style plot, Histogram for example, works just fine.

**Is this a quirk of ProbabilityScalePlot or am I missing something?**

If I simplify the input to it's bare-bones (and change the data, sorry):

```
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image: Getting an error...]

and then look at the `GridLines` part of `InputForm` (formatted and comments added to hopefully make it easier to read):

```
GridLines ->
    {
     (* X-axis *)
     Charting`ScaledTickValues[
       {#1 & , #1 & },
       Charting`ScaledTickValues[{#1 & , #1 & }][##1]
     ] & ,

     (* Y-axis *)
     Charting`ScaledTickValues[
       {1 + SpecialFunctions`Probit[#1] & ,
        (1*Erfc[(1*(Sqrt[2.] - Sqrt[2.]*#1))/2.])/2. &
       },
       Charting`ScaledTickValues[{#1*0.01 & , #1 & }][##1]
     ] &
    }
```

It appears that it's correctly assigning *something* to the x and y axis, but based on the error I assume that it's not evaluating to a list of numbers or grid line specifications. Sadly that `InputForm` is a bit too complicated for me to read fully, but I can tell that it's using the Z-score of the data point as the actual grid lines or tick marks, but then transforming it to cumulative probability when displaying the y-axis.

Comment: I didn't read too carefully, but if you know where you want the `y`-axis gridlines to be, you can manually input them. For example, `ProbabilityScalePlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 100}], "Normal", 
 AspectRatio -> 0.9, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {Automatic, {1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, 99}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize -> Large, Thick, Purple], 
 FrameLabel -> {"Value", "Cum. Prob."}, ImageSize -> 500]` produces a chart with the gridlines where you want them. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus That doesn't work for me - it reports the "A GridLines specification should be None, Automatic, or a list of grid line specifications" error. I didn't mention it before, but I'm using Mathematica v8 (post updated).

Comment: This is a bug in V8 and V9. Fixed in V10.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Awesome, thanks for the info.

Comment: @Mike I don't think it is fixed in v10, at least not in all cases.  Try the examples in dthor's self-answer.  The scaling is not handled correctly in the case of negative numbers.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you're right. I originally just tested the example above in V8,9, and 10. I just ran all 9 examples in the self answer and the first gave a pink box. the remaining 8 were fine. V10.0.2 on OS X 10.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Looks like it's a bug:

After more research and test cases, it appears that this is a bug in Mathematica **8**. I have no way of checking older or newer versions. Perhaps someone could execute the following test case code and verify?

**In Mathematica 8**:

The `GridLines->{x, y}` option of `ProbabilityScalePlot` does not work as expected under the following circumstances:

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                               | X GridLine spec has value <= 0 |
+                               +--------------------------------+
|                               |   True       |  False          |
+-------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+
| One or Both GridLine  |  True | No gridlines | Error           |
| specs are "Automatic" |       | displayed;   |                 |
|                       |       | No Error     |                 |
|                       +-------+--------------+-----------------+
|                       | False | No gridlines | OK              |
|                       |       | displayed;   |                 |
|                       |       | No Error     |                 |
+-----------------------+-------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Go ahead and try out the following Test Cases and see what you get:

First, generate some data from the Normal distribution. The data should have both positive and negative values in order to really see where things freak out.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], 100];
```

### These result in an error:

```
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {Automatic, {1, 2, 3}}]
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {{1, 2, 3}, Automatic}]
```

### These result in no gridlines being displayed and no error thrown:

```
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 5, 50, 95, 99}}]
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {{-1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 5, 50, 95, 99}}]
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {{0, 1, 2, 3}, Automatic}]
```

### And these test cases work as expected:

```
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> Automatic]
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {None, {1, 5, 50, 95, 99}}]
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {{1, 2, 3}, {10, 50, 95, 99}}]
```

Comment: With V10.0.2 on OS X 10.10.1 I ran all your examples and the first gave a error. The remaining 8 were fine.

Answer (score 3):

A problem still exists with the scaling of grid lines in version 10.0.2.  I'll try to explore this later if I have time but for now here is a work-around.  Specify the horizontal lines in the plot command and the vertical lines in `Show`, then combine with [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html).

```
gr = ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", GridLines -> {None, {1, 5, 50, 95, 99}}];

Overlay[{
  gr,
  Show[gr, GridLines -> {{-2, -1, 1, 2, 3}, None}]
}]
```

[image]

As a for-your-information example one must realize that the actual *y* scale of the `Graphics` is not what the plot shows:

```
Show[gr, FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The actual plot range is revealed with;

```
PlotRange[gr]  (* undocumented usage *)
```

> ```
> {{-4.38919, 5.86036}, {-1.4587, 3.4587}}
> ```

Comment: When I was looking at the `InputForm` for the function, I noticed the PlotRange thing too: Mathematica is using the Z-score (# Std Dev away from mean) as the *actual* range, but then transforming it to the cumulative probability when displaying.

Answer (score 1):

`ProbabilityScalePlot` uses `FrameTicks`.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 100];
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", 
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Range[-3, 4, .5], None}}]
```

So if you want to choose your x-axis ticks (here, between -4 and 4 in steps of 0.5), then make the ticks go across the figure in this way:

```
ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Normal", 
 FrameTicks -> {Table[{x, x, {.5, 0}}, {x, -4, 4, .5}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's the lateral gridlines, those associated with Y values, that I'm most interested in. During my search for a solution, I actually found what I think is a bug in `ProbabilityScalePlot`: try adding the option `GridLines->{Automatic, Automatic}` - in Mathematica 8, it errors out.

Comment: I use Mma 10.0.0, so can't check bugs in earlier versions.  If there's a true bug, there's not much I can do to help except suggest ugly and awkward combinations of separate plot and grid array figures.  Or, of course, compute your own CDFs and plot with a non-buggy plot function.

Comment: I think it's most definitely a bug. I've already sent Wolfram the bug report. See my Answer for details on the bug, if interested.